# Counting and Joining in SQL (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My database contains 2 tables called products and product_categories.

Product_categories contain category_id and category_name
Products contain category_id and other irrelevant info for this question.

I need to count the number of products using category_id from the products table and also display their name which is in the product_categories table.

```
Select * FROM product_categories
```

displays :

```
category_id, category_name
    1   CPU
    2   Video Card
    3   RAM
    4   Mother Board
    5   Storage
```

And

```
Select * FROM products
```

displays (condensed):

```
                category_id
399.77  564.89  1
481.56  554.99  1
4058.99 5499.99 2
3619.14 4139    2
2505.04 3254.99 2
... UPTO CATEGORY_ID 5
```

Current statement :

```
SELECT category_id , COUNT (1) AS "TOTAL"
FROM products
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Output:

```
Category_id, total
    1   70
    2   50
    5   108
    4   60
```

DESIRED RESULT: I need to display the category id followed by category name and finally the total number of products.

Comment: Specify the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join those tables:

```
select p.category_id,
       c.category_name,
       count(*) as total
from products p join product_categories c on c.category_id = p.category_id
group by p.category_id,
         c.category_name
```

You might want to turn it to outer join if you want to display categories that don't exist in the `products` table.